# Is there really no FULL freeing link deletion function in GLib lists API?

Tags: api, doubly-linked-list, glib

Problem: I would like to remove a link from GList and release its data – at **single step**. The available, related GLib functions are:

- [g_list_remove_link](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Doubly-Linked-Lists.html#g-list-remove-link) - it only removes link from list without touching both removed link and its data,
- [g_list_delete_link](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Doubly-Linked-Lists.html#g-list-delete-link) – it's close, however besides removing **and freeing** the linked element control structure (i.e.: GList struct), it doesn't touch data hold in it.

That's all and it's unsufficient… I would like a function, e.g.:

- `g_list_delete_link_full(GList *lst, GList *el, GDestroyNotify full_free_func)`,

that would also run a full-cleanup function on data of passed GList node…

Why no such function? I wouldn't expect to occurr any obviously missing functions from GLib API, and this one IMO is such a situation. Or I'm missing something from API?

Answer (score 1):

There’s no such function to do that because it’s only two calls to do it yourself:

```
my_free_func (link->data);
list = g_list_delete_link (list, link);
```